# Book recommendation: Descriptive Logics

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am wanting to understand description logics as the basis for ontologies (OWL and beyond). The [Description Logic Primer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4089.pdf) gets us a good way towards this, but gives no treatment of Datatypes. [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/142009050X) also gives no treatment of datatypes other than to say that they don't significantly change the logic and to hint at a more powerful datatypes capability (not in OWL) called concrete domains, which they invite the reader to references in a non-existent (in my copy) section.

So I am wanting a book that will treat DLs much more completely, without hand-waiving away Datatypes (and attributes) and hopefully that will treat datatypes both in the way of OWL, and also go in the eluded to concrete domains. A treatment of embedding these within First Order Logic would also be appreciated.

Comment: Franz Baader, Ian Horrocks, etc (editors), [An Introduction to Description Logic (2017, Cambridge University Press)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Description_Logic/xtUoDwAAQBAJ)

Comment: Also Franz Baader etc (editors), [The Description Logic Handbook (Cambridge UP, 2003)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Description_Logic_Handbook/e6_hJtM07qwC)